# How to include "/" or "@" in XML elements?

Tags: xml

I'm creating an XML file and have elements like this `/tns:Faktura/@typ`

Meaning the record would look like:

`</tns:Faktura/@typ>G<//tns:Faktura/@typ>`
`</tns:Faktura/tns:P_1>43285<//tns:Faktura/tns:P_1>`
`</tns:Faktura/tns:P_106E_2>false<//tns:Faktura/tns:P_106E_2>`
`</tns:Faktura/tns:P_106E_3>false<//tns:Faktura/tns:P_106E_3>`

I've tried to substitute the invalid characters, but can't get it to work.
My header is just the standard. I'm closing the record and the schema as intended with each closing tag.

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>`

`<JPK_FAS_SALES_INVOICES xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">`

I'm trying to export an excel file to XML, which will then be read by TAX authorities and they need the headers to stay intact for their software to be able to read the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XML element should never look like this

> XML elements must follow these naming rules:
>
> - Element names are case-sensitive
> - Element names must start with a letter or underscore
> - Element names cannot start with the letters xml (or XML, or Xml, etc)
> - **Element names can contain letters, digits, hyphens, underscores, and periods**
> - Element names cannot contain spaces
>
> Any name can be used, no words are reserved (except xml).

Also from what I see your XML should probably look like something like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<JPK_FAS_SALES_INVOICES xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:tns="http://www.yournamespace.com/tns">
    <!-- ... -->
    <tns:Faktura typ="G">
        <tns:P_1>43285</tns:P_1>
        <tns:P_106E_2>false</tns:P_106E_2>
        <tns:P_106E_3>false</tns:P_106E_3>
    </tns:Faktura>
    <!-- ... -->
</JPK_FAS_SALES_INVOICES>
```

Don't forget to define your namespace `tns`

Comment: Thank you. So you show: `/tns:Faktura/@typ` is `<tns:Faktura typ="G">
        <tns:P_1>43285</tns:P_1>
        <tns:P_106E_2>false</tns:P_106E_2>
        <tns:P_106E_3>false</tns:P_106E_3>`

So what if I have `/tns:Faktura/tns:P_13_1/#agg` How should I handle the #?

Answer (score 1):

The element names must fulfill the requirements enounced in [3.2 Element Type Declarations](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml11/#elemdecls). In particular, an element name is a `[name][2]` and is build that way:

> ```
> [4]       NameStartChar      ::=      ":" | [A-Z] | "_" | [a-z] | [#xC0-#xD6] | [#xD8-#xF6] | [#xF8-#x2FF] | [#x370-#x37D] | [#x37F-#x1FFF] | [#x200C-#x200D] | [#x2070-#x218F] | [#x2C00-#x2FEF] | [#x3001-#xD7FF] | [#xF900-#xFDCF] | [#xFDF0-#xFFFD] | [#x10000-#xEFFFF]
> [4a]      NameChar       ::=      NameStartChar | "-" | "." | [0-9] | #xB7 | [#x0300-#x036F] | [#x203F-#x2040]
> [5]       Name       ::=      NameStartChar (NameChar)*
> ```

Put more clearly you are not allowed to use `/` and `@` in your element names.